# How can I return a variable from within a "for" loop inside a mouseEntered method?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I've made a stadiumPanel class that contains a two-dimensional array of JButtons, each with their own MouseListener. Each button corresponds to a "Seat" object, which contains a set of data (inside a separate data class), and when I hover over the button with the mouse, I want to grab the data that corresponds to that button and display it in my parent class (a JWindow).

To do this, I'm trying to use two nested "for" loops inside the MouseEntered() method, which then uses MouseEvent.getSource() to search for the hovered-over JButton (and consequently the index corresponding to the correct Seat). A Seat object at the given index is then returned using my "stad.getSeat" method. Then, from the for loop, I want to store that seat in my "seatHovered" variable so I can access the data corresponding to that Seat from another class. However, I can't manage to change the hoveredSeat variable from within the "for" loop.

How can I do this?

```
public class StadiumPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{

Seat hoveredSeat;
Stadium stad;
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[Stadium.ROWS+1][Stadium.COLUMNS+1];


public StadiumPanel(Stadium s){

stad = s;

for (int row = 0; row < Stadium.ROWS; row++){
  for (int col = 0; col < Stadium.COLUMNS; col++){
      buttons[row][col] = new JButton();
      add(buttons[row][col]);
      buttons[row][col].addMouseListener(this);
    }
  }
}


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{
  for (int row = 0; row < Stadium.ROWS; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < Stadium.COLUMNS; col++){
      if (e.getSource() == buttons[row][col] && buttons[row][col] != null){ 
           hoveredSeat = stad.getSeat(row,col);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My apologies if this question is ridiculously confusing. Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: How can you say that `hoveredSeat` has not changed? You are not using the variable anywhere after changing! Also I could not find the declaration of `JButton[][] buttons;`

Comment: For sake of clarity I condensed the code and left out parts that were fairly irrelevant. I'll add a bit more, but if I post all of it, it will likely be difficult to follow.
Regarding the use of the hoveredSeat variable, I'm accessing the variable from another class after changing it, it just isn't shown here.

Comment: Ok. Since you can have only one possible `hoveredSeat` at any given time, I would suggest you to make it `static`, and access from the other class as `StadiumPanel.hoveredSeat`. If you do not want to make it `static` then make it `volatile`. Also I will suggest you to try displaying the info of `hoveredSeat` inside `mouseEntered()` method to check whether `getSeat()` is working correctly or not (for debugging).